# Evaluating methods in parallel

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, parallelism-amdahl, concurrent-processing

Let's say I need the output from the below independent methods

```
var x = LongCalculation(123)
var y = LongCalculation2(345)
var z = LongCalculation3(678)
var b = LongCalculation4(910)
```

What is the least code invasive way of executing these calculations in parallel, without destroying the readability of the logic? I know of `Parallel.Foreach()` but in this case there is no list of items to process, only independent method calls.

Comment: If you specify the operation type inside `LongCalculations` it is much easy to answer your question.

Comment: After all administratively executed censoring deletions, you might miss the key property of the Problem-under-Review. All the calls achieve at most a just-[CONCURRENT] code-execution, as documented under Theodor's A. altogether with an MCVE-code as proof. Adding any "terminal"-blocking barrier introduces an artificial blocking of all paths of (so far independent,uncoordinated just-[CONCURRENT]) code-execution,which may & can align/release 'em once all-finished (Yet what happens if anyone blocks infinitely is easy to guess: Apollo 11 moon-landing would crash,wouldn't it?) yet still NOT parallel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess the least invasive way is using Parallel.Invoke:

```
long x, y, z, b;
Parallel.Invoke(
    () => x = LongCalculation(123),
    () => y = LongCalculation2(345),
    () => z = LongCalculation3(678),
    () => b = LongCalculation4(910)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make a list of items to process out of your code:

```
int x,y,z,b;
List<Action> actions = new List<Action>
{
    () => x = LongCalculation(123),
    () => y = LongCalculation2(345),
    () => z = LongCalculation3(678),
    () => b = LongCalculation4(910)
};
Parallel.ForEach(actions, x => x.Invoke());
```

Online demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/xy7sxF

Comment: This is a good approach. Something to have in mind is that in case of an exception in any of the 4 methods, the variables `x`, `y`, `z`, and `b` might end up being partially initialized.

Answer (score 0):

Using the [`Task.Run`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run) and the [`Task.WaitAll`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.waitall) should be quite readable:

```
var task1 = Task.Run(() => LongCalculation(123));
var task2 = Task.Run(() => LongCalculation2(345));
var task3 = Task.Run(() => LongCalculation3(678));
var task4 = Task.Run(() => LongCalculation4(910));
Task.WaitAll(task1, task2, task3, task4);
var x = task1.Result;
var y = task2.Result;
var z = task3.Result;
var b = task4.Result;
```

This assuming that limiting the degree of parallelism of the CPU-bound operations is not a requirement.

Comment: Thanks but I found this very invasive and makes the logic much more difficult to understand.

Comment: @alenyb yep, it's not the prettiest thing. The selling point of this approach is that the `x`, `y`, `z`, and `b` variables are assigned on the current thread. Which might be important if instead of variables they are actually properties of a non-thread-safe object.

Comment: What is an approximate add-on cost spent to enter one new item into a thread-pool Queue (as ref'd by the URL) at executing one `.Run()`-method in [ns]? What is the approximate add-on overhead cost of maintaining such a Queue Dispatcher ( governing task-scheduling and task-marshalling overhead operations so as to yield each task to actual working-thread once a thread-pool signals an empty thread becoming RTO ) in [ns] per 1 [ms]? You might also prefer to revise your text "...degree of parallelism...", while a code-execution flow is by far not parallel but a just-[CONCURRENT] w. a barrier added

Comment: @user3666197 I can't tell these exact metrics on top of my head. I know that the overhead of `Task.Run` is pretty small, to a point of being negligible for most practical applications. Feel free to experiment and report your measurements if you want. The other solutions proposed in this question (`Parallel.ForEach`/`Parallel.Invoke`) are using tasks too internally. The term "degree of parallelism" [is used by these commonly used APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.paralleloptions.maxdegreeofparallelism), I didn't invent it myself.